# Stitching together badly formatted log files

Tags: performance, beginner, csv, r

I needed to stitch together a large number of badly formatted log files. I [painfully] developed a script for it in R, one that successfully dealt with the various flaws in the dataset. However, this script is rather slow. Considering I'm a neophyte to the field (and don't know what I do not know), I was hoping I could get some suggestions on how to speed this code up - using either R, or any other Windows-based/CLI tools.

```
#Getting path for all files within a particular directory. 
files = list.files(path = dirs[j], full.names = T)

#The files are in csv format and in the ideal case have exactly 5 columns. However, the 5th column can contain an arbitary number of commas. If I try to fread with sep = ",", certain rows can be of arbitarily high length. If I use select = 1:5 to subset each row, I lose data. 

#My solution was to read each line into a single column and then seperate into columns within the script based on the location of the first 4 commas.  
data <- rbindlist(lapply(files,fread,sep = "\n",fill = T,header = F))

#Removing empty rows.
retain <- unlist(lapply(data, function(x) {
       str_detect(x,".")
   }))
data[retain,] -> data

#Removing rows where there is no data in the 5th column. 
retain <- unlist(lapply(data, function(x) {
       str_detect(trimws(x,which ='both') ,".+,.+,.*,.*,.+")
   }))
data[retain,] -> data

#This replaces the first 4 commas with a tab-delimiter. 
for(i in 1:4){
data <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) {
                    str_replace(x,",","\t")
              }),stringsAsFactors = F)
}

#This splits the row into 5 seperate columns, always. 
data <- unlist(lapply(data, function(x) {
  unlist(strsplit(x,"\t",fixed = T))
}))

#Changes the format from a character vector to a data table. 
data = data.frame(matrix(data,ncol=5,byrow = T),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. The focus of this site is to review *working* code. From your question, it looks like the code does work, but it's slow, and you're not sure why. That's fine, though. However, you should [edit] your post to show that your code does indeed work and describe the log files a little bit. Also, the current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @Abs can you supply first `data` example?

Comment: @Abs why dont you read in data with `sep = ','`?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly your data structure, I have to guess that it looks like this:

```
data <- data.table(a = c('1,1,1,4,6',
                         '1,2,3,4,',
                         '',
                         '1,2,3,4,',
                         '1,2,3,4,5'))
```

If it is correct, then your desired operations could be done like this:

```
#############################################
#Removing empty rows.
data <- data[data[[1]] != '']

#Removing rows where there is no data in the 5th column. 
retain <- str_detect(trimws(data[[1]], which = 'both') ,".+,.+,.*,.*,.+")
data <- data[retain, ]

#This replaces the first 4 commas with a tab-delimiter. 
for(i in 1:4) data[[1]] <- str_replace(data[[1]], ",", "\t")

#This splits the row into 5 seperate columns, always. 
dNew <- as.data.table(tstrsplit(data[[1]], "\t", fixed = T))
dNew
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1:  1  1  1  4  6
# 2:  1  2  3  4  5
```

The main problem is that you are using `lapply` where it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using R for such a task is an overkill and wasteful.   This is easier and quicker done with some common command line tools.  But afterwards it's trivial to work in R.

You can quickly fix these files using `sed`.

There is a detailed description how to adjust the first occurrences in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155805/sed-replace-first-k-instances-of-a-word-in-the-file)
The idea would be to select a non-offending separator - say `;`

Similarly lines  can be deleted as shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-lines-in-a-text-file-that-contain-a-specific-string).

So this turns the first 4 `,` into `;` (4 times the same instruction), deletes all lines that don't contain 4 `;` and creates a backup of the files with extension `.old`.  The `*.csv` does it for all files in the directory.

```
sed -i.old -e 's/,/;/' -e 's/,/;/' -e 's/,/;/' -e 's/,/;/' -e "/^\(.*;\)\{4\}.*\$/!d" *.csv
```

Of course run this over a **copy**!  Might need a few tweaks for windows.